# Android: selectableItemBackground not working on button with xml drawable

Tags: android, xml

I made a rounded button with xml drawable and applied `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` in hope of getting a ripple effect. However, ripple effect does not work. Is there anyway to make the ripple effect work? As a workaround I wrapped the button with a `FrameLayout` and applied `android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"` to it, but in that case the ripple is rectangular and goes beyond button (as it is rounded).

xml:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/reg_next"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="@string/next"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_background"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
```

rounded_button_background:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#ebeff1"/> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#979797" />
    <corners
        android:radius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create ripple drawable and set it as button background (without foreground attribute):

rounded_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="#2793c9">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ebeff1" /> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
            <stroke
                android:width="1px"
                android:color="#979797" />
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:radius="20dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
                android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

If you want support api bellow 21 (without ripple effect), add this drawable to directory **drawable-v21** and in directory **drawable** create these files:

rounded_btn_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ebeff1" /> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#979797" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:radius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

rounded_btn_active.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#2793c9" /> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->
    <stroke
        android:width="1px"
        android:color="#979797" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:radius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

rounded_button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_btn_active" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_btn_normal" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Special thanks for pointing out solution for API level below v21 that many ignore.

Comment: Thaks for response, or if you want use ripple effect below api 21, you may use some lib e.g. [RippleEffect](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)